# Parse.com Cloud Code - Why is useMasterKey() required for creating and saving objects

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to create and save a new object when a new account is created. I'm using the following code.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) {
    var userDataObjectId = request.object.get("userDataObjectId");
    if(!userDataObjectId) {
        console.log("NEW USER");
        var userData = new Parse.Object("UserData");
        userData.save(null, {
            success: function(userData) {
                console.log("SUCCEEDED SAVING USERDATA");
            },
            error: function(userData, error) {
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I get the "NEW USER" log output but the only way to make sure the `UserData` object is saved is to add `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()`.

I don't understand why the Master key is necessary to create and save an object that I haven't put any Class Level Permissions on, and when even clients can create and save objects without any issue!

I haven't seen anything related to the master key being required for creating and saving objects of normal classes. Could anybody clear this up for me please? Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Following Russel's instructions, I got the following output in the userData save error.

```
##################################################
# Alert                                          #
##################################################
#                                                #
# Error: 209 invalid session token               #
#                                                #
#                                         [ OK ] #
#                                                #
##################################################
```

I searched for this particular error and tried reinstalling the app (Android) like suggessted in some of the SO posts. This didn't help. Also I already had "Require Revocable Sessions" option enabled, if that's relevant.

Comment: What is the output of the `userData` save? Are there any error codes or console logs?

Comment: @Russell no output at all. It fails silently without the master key.

Comment: In the error handler of the userData save, change it to the following `error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message); }`. Then see if we can get any useful messages.

Comment: @Russell Please see the update to the question. I added the log output in userData save error.

Comment: When I first started experimenting with cloud code, I remember being able to save a new UserData object in beforeSave() without master key. Now I cannot save object in both beforeSave() and aftersave() without master key. It's really weird.

Comment: Did you enable revokable sessions during that time? Try logging out and logging back in so that the user has a valid session token. Whether it's related or not, it's still an issue which should be solved

Comment: @Russell My app is pretty new, and according to the Parse blog, revocable sessions are enabled for all new apps. So yes, it was enabled from the start and I never changed it. I think my issue is due to a bug.

Comment: @Russell I'm trying to save the UserData object on sign-up, so logging out and then logging back in will not help. After testing the afterSave() by creating an account from my Android app, I delete the User and Session from the Data browser, and then I repeat. Maybe this bug is related to deleting User and Session objects from the Data Browser.

Comment: Do you have any before/after save hooks on the `UserData` class? Specifically, any kind of validation that requires the user to be logged in (have a valid session). If you require that a user be logged in first, it's possible there is a race condition where the user is not yet logged in when trying to create the `UserData` object.

Comment: Hey @Russell thanks for your continued effort to help me. I only have main.js and signup.js files. main.js only contains an include line for signup.js which contains only the code given in the question. But oh yeah! I remember uploading another userdata.js file containing before or aftersave hook on UserData class which only made a console.log(). The file is no longer live though. I think that all my experimentation has led to this condition where I need to use master key. I didn't actually delete the userdata.js file. I uploaded an empty file because I didn't see an option to delete it.

Comment: @Russell The userdata.js file no longer appears in my dashboard.

Comment: There is probably some kind of validation that requires a user to be logged in (i.e. have a valid session) in order to to create the new `UserData` object. From Parse blog: "When users log in or sign up, the Parse Cloud automatically creates the corresponding Session object. When users log out, the Parse Cloud automatically destroys the corresponding Session object, which invalidates the session token that was previously assigned to that user’s device." It's possible this is a bug that you could report to Parse. I would expect that the session should be created by the afterSave

Comment: [Possibly related link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004227/cloudcode-user-aftersave-requires-usemasterkey-why). [Another related link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003348/invalid-session-error-parse-aftersave-on-user-in-cloud-code)

Comment: @Russell I'm just gonna settle for using the master code since I trust the code. Anyway, thanks for your time, Russell!

Answer (score 0):

A user cannot change User objects other than its own. In this case, there is no logged in user (currentUser), so you can't save it directly and therefore must useMasterKey.

Have a look at signup in the Android guide: https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#users-signing-up

Comment: I'm actually creating and saving a UserData object in _User afterSave. UserData is a class that I created and it isn't a User class. Thanks for your replay though. :)